# How to hold android device in dim-wakelock with disabled touchscreen?

Tags: android, accelerometer, wakelock

I want to write an app that needs accelerometer data while the user has the device in his pocket. However, at least on my phone (Motorola Defy with a nightly CM9 build), a dim-wakelock is needed because the accelerometer somehow turns off together with the screen. But if the screen stays turned on, the user might trigger random touch actions with his body movements. I could just display a black area, but that won't protect the menu keys. So, what should I do to protect the device from accidential user interaction? Things that come to my mind:

- use root access to somehow hook deep into the system and require an unlock pattern or so - but I as a user would hesitate to give an app root just because it wants to block my input, and if I as coder make a mistake, I might lock out users -> might work, but probably the worst possible solution
- somehow use the lock screen for this - but I don't know how I can safely, whatever the settings on the device may be, activate that lock screen without needing root

Gah, this all just looks bad to me. Is there any way to solve this that doesn't suck?

Comment: Couldn't you poll the accelerometer in a background service, bypassing the need for the wakelock in the first place?

Comment: @Geobits: That's what I tried, but it received no data while the screen was turned off.

Comment: I thought that might be too easy an answer. It may be a device/ROM specific problem, I've seen it work on a couple Samsung phones.

Comment: Some input devices are disabled temprorarily on the kernel level when the device goes to sleep – to exclude a device from that, you have to write a kernel module and fiddle around with pointers in the kernel. Not so nice. (But I do have a working implementation of that which works on my phone now! :D)